How can i just calculate a part of grad using make_functional in PyTorch?
func_model, func_params = make_functional(self.model)
def fm(x, func_params):
                    fx = func_model(func_params, x)
                    return fx.squeeze(0).squeeze(0)
def floss(func_params,input):
                    fx = fm(input, func_params)
                    return fx
                
per_sample_grads =vmap(jacrev(floss), (None, 0))(func_params, input)
cnt=0
for g in per_sample_grads: 
                g = g.detach()
                J_d = g.reshape(len(g),-1) if cnt == 0 else torch.hstack([J_d,g.reshape(len(g),-1)])
                cnt = 1
                
result = J_d.detach()

In this code, per_sample_grads includes all the grad of a network model by inputting some data. Where the model
self.model = Network(self.input_size, self.hidden_size,  self.output_size, self.depth, act=torch.nn.Tanh() )

I use this code to compute the Jacobian matrix. [ Jacobian matrix : data number * parameter number ]However, what I want to get is a certain small part of grad.
params = torch.cat([p.view(-1) for p in self.model.parameters()], dim=0)
selected_columns = torch.random.choice(p_number, opt_num, replace=False)
target_params=params[selected_columns]# I just need to caculate the grads of the target_params

And getting the all the gradient is some kind of waste in my codes. I want to save some time in this auto_grad step. What can I do to achieve that?
How can I compute the gradients for only part of the model to save time?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
